# Short story about dead soldiers bodies being reused

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, zombie

I read the story many years ago. The solar system was being invaded by insectoid aliens who greatly outnumbered Earth's population. All available people were involved in the war effort and all women were encouraged to have as many children as possible. The story centers around an officer who must command a war ship crewed by artificial people. The protagonist was sterile, I think. The crew's bodies were made up of the bodies of corpses of war dead.

Comment: This sort of reminds me of [The Ghost Brigrades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghost_Brigades) by John Scalzi, but there are enough differences that I don't believe it to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think I remember this story, but not the title/author.  In the story I'm thinking of, the resurrected soldiers are referred to as "globs".  One of them expresses his resentment that they are all created sterile when he assumes it would be a simple matter to have them be fertile.  The (human) officer shares that he himself is sterile due to an injury, and it is not a simple matter to fix.

Comment: Thanks.  Now that you mention it I seem to remember that the protagonist was sterile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's ["Down Among the Dead Men"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45782) by William Tenn.  They were called "blobs" not "globs".

[From the SF Encyclopedia:](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/zombies)

> . . . William Tenn's "Down Among the Dead Men" (June 1954 Galaxy), where "human protoplasm reclamation" creates fully human and intelligent (though sterile) new soldiers who are subject to discrimination and abuse as "zombies" or "blobs" . . .

When the viewpoint character admits his sterility, it somewhat reconciles the resurrected soldiers to their fate.

Comment: Thanks I have been trying to recall this for ages.

Answer (score 5):

Not too sure, but could this be *We All Died at Breakaway Station* by Richard C. Meredith. There isn't a whole lot about it online except for various reviews, but here's an excerpt of one of them:

"Now the Jillies are massing to attack Breakaway Station. This station is only lightly defended and unless reinforcements can be delivered in time, the Jillies will take it.

Earth however has no regular forces close enough to protect the station. The only possible reinforcement is a hospital ship and the two battle cruisers escorting it back to Earth. The hospital ship carries the frozen remains of thousands of solders who may still be revived and repaired. The crews of the ships are war casualties themselves, still desperately injured, temporarily repaired, some rebuilt as cyborgs.

Captain Absolom Bracer is now only half-human, his head and chest mounted upon a medical pedestal, and with one prosthetic arm and one mechanical. As captain, he needs his wits about him, he must stay alert, so he doesn't take his painkillers and he *hurts*."

http://www.sfreviews.com/docs/Richard%20C.%20Meredith_1969_We%20All%20Died%20At%20Breakaway%20Station.htm