# SciFi book featuring an alien race called the Jillies or Gillies

Tags: story-identification, novel

A spaceship crewed by a physically and psychologically scarred crew must fight off hostile aliens called the Jillies/Gillies and destroy their home world. Novel circa 1970's.

Answer (score 12):

This could be Richard C. Meredith's *[We All Died at Breakaway Station](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?16334)* (1969), as referenced in [this previous unaccepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/i-am-looking-for-the-title-of-a-short-story-about-dead-soldiers-bodies-being-reu) to a question about a novel with a similar premise. The enemy aliens are called the "Jillies", as seen in the quote from a review in that answer:

> Now the Jillies are massing to attack Breakaway Station. This station
> is only lightly defended and unless reinforcements can be delivered in
> time, the Jillies will take it.
>
> Earth however has no regular forces close enough to protect the
> station. The only possible reinforcement is a hospital ship and the
> two battle cruisers escorting it back to Earth. The hospital ship
> carries the frozen remains of thousands of solders who may still be
> revived and repaired. The crews of the ships are war casualties
> themselves, still desperately injured, temporarily repaired, some
> rebuilt as cyborgs.

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much! I appreciate your help!