# Looking for a short story about "zombies" (artificial humans") and a space war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/205221/why-would-they-use-human-soldiers-over-undead-ones) over on "World Building" reminded me of a short story I read a long time ago.  I would have read it in the mid 1990s or earlier.  The story itself would have been much older.

In the story, humans are involved in a space war.  It seems things aren't going so well, so they've started building "zombie crewmen" out of the bits of biological debris left over from their dead crewmen.  We're not talking reanimation here.  Think "scrape the dead dudes off the walls and use them as raw material." There is mention of deliveries of "material" as "bales." Like the ["bales" of scrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_crusher) that comes out of a car crusher, but made of bits and pieces of multiple dead crewmen.

The story itself is about a naturally born, newly promoted commander of a small ship (scout or some such that only needs a few crewmen.)

He is sent to the "factory" where they produce the "zombies" to pick up the crew for his new ship.

Part of the story involves reminiscences about when the zombies were first produced - slow, stupid, suitable only for menial tasks.  There's specifically mention of having to remember to "turn off" a zombie crewman.  Rather, remember to tell them to stop.  The example was that if you told one to polish the bulkhead, it'd keep on polishing the bulkhead until it had worn through the wall.

The newer zombies were better.  As good as naturally born human beings in almost all ways.

The new crew was **not** pleased to meet their new commander.  They had been exposed to a lot of prejudice during their training, and were resentful of their treatment.  That, and the one thing that zombies couldn't do - father children.

The commander talks to the crewman to find out why they resent him on first sight - the prejudices of the trainers comes out, as well as the reproduction issue.

They assume that the reproductive ability has been held back to differentiate between zombies and humans.

The commander knows different.  If the medical folks could give the zombies reproductive powers, then they'd also be able to fix sterility in humans - and the commander is sterile due to a near hit on his previous ship with some kind of radioactive weapon.

In the end, the commander and the crew bond over their common disability, with the implication that they are going to go out and be heroes so that they'll at least be remembered for their actions.

---

The humans call the zombies more nasty things than just "zombies." They also call them "blobs."  There are probably more that I don't remember.

The zombies in turn have their own words for naturally born humans.  The commander invites his crew to use them all on him and get it out their systems.  He specifically mentions being called "eutie" and "wombat" because he thought words were cute when used in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[Down Among the Dead Men](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45782)" (1954) by William Tenn.  There is a previous question about it: [Short story about dead soldiers bodies being reused](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71462/short-story-about-dead-soldiers-bodies-being-reused)

Comment: Yep.  That's it.  I even up voted that question years ago, though I had forgotten it.

Comment: I recognized this one instantly because it was one of the first questions I asked: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199559/new-attack-ship-captain-is-finally-accepted-by-his-crew-when-he-reveals-hes-ste